# Right-aligned icon within button at any width

Tags: css, icons, css-float

This should be simple, but I'm having problems getting a robust solution. Basically I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: button examples]

So, an element (`a` or `button`) with an icon right-aligned, using an icon font. I need to ensure that:

1. The button can be any width
2. Without an icon present, there is no excess padding on the button
3. The text and icon always remain on the same line (don't wrap)

Here's the HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Download <span data-icon="+"></span></button>
```

And the (S)CSS:

```
.btn {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: none;
    background-color: #535B99;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    [data-icon] {
        float: right;
        padding-left: 10px;
        &:before { content: attr(data-icon); }
    }
}
```

You can see this in [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/GyA8F/). The problem is, unless I add a width to the `.btn` class, the icon always drops a line. Absolute positioning would work, but then I'd fail to meet (2) above as it would require some padding. What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I missed one other criteria:

4.) At 100% width, the icon is aligned to the right (not next to the text)

So in some cases, it'll look like:

[image: 100% width version]

Which is why the `float` is necessary in my CSS.

**SOLUTION**

Based almost entirely on @Riskbreaker's solution, [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/R3V3E/) what I settled on:

```
<button data-button-icon="+" class="btn" href="#">Click Me :P</button>

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    border: medium none;
    background-color: #535B99;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: left;    
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    &:after {
      content: attr(data-button-icon);
      float: right;
      padding-left: 1em;
    }
}
```

Basically, abandoning the separate `span` and using just the `button` element, which has the benefit of less extraneous markup.

Comment: nice question on my way after a long time :) trying to provide you with one.

Comment: Excellent glad "we" resolved it!  Nice job still integrating your way :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just **take float:right out** of `[data-icon]`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/GyA8F/4/)

If you need to be specific with width (Pixels or Percentages),... then yes you do need **float: right** so you then need an inner div to control both:

```
<div>Create Advert HELLO YOU ALL <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="+"></span></div>
```

[**Demo with float:right**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/GyA8F/28/)

As you can see I added width: 300px, and width: 100% works but this is more manual....this is construsively more manual(meaning being specific with your button)...but it works.

So either *no width/no float:right* needed or *add width/float:right* needed.

================================================================================
OK so your dilemma is ***you do not want to deal with dimensions***, I made this not using your method but mines using no spans at all...this is my last suggestion:

**http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/st3m2/1/**

What you see here is the **:before or :after**(*doesn't matter which just as long as you have the right padding and float method*) method is the best way to get this resolve and my class added the content: plus. Removing "add" class will make the button look right and adding 100% will always have the icon right :)

Comment: Your answer is better. I removed my answer.

Comment: I missed one important point, which means this solution unfortunately won't work. Question has been updated - cheers.

Comment: Adding a width (or an extra class) is exactly what I'm trying to avoid here. I'm looking for something robust that will work at any width.

Comment: In that case why not add the "+" as a background ? Positioning it in the right place and then no more width worries

Comment: Two reasons:
1) I'd still need (conditional) padding so that the text didn't overlap the icon
2) I'd lose the many benefits that using icon fonts brings

Comment: I see your dilemma..If no one else responds i can think of something else soon

Comment: OK last edit on my main answer up top, this is the best way i can think of your question

Comment: Thanks for all your help - I've accepted your answer as it was so close to what I require and it prompted me to think about the problem slightly differently. I've added a comment and link above to show how I adapted your fiddle to remove the dependency on separate classes.